# Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name

Tags: django, django-urls

models.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

app_name = "Review"

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^books/', include("Review.urls", namespace='reviews')),
]
```

Review\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import (
  ReviewUpdate,
  ReviewDelete,
)

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^reviews/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', ReviewUpdate.as_view(), name='review_update'),
  url(r'^reviews/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', ReviewDelete.as_view(), name='review_delete'),
]
```

I am providing app_name before my urlpatterns. But it's giving me error while running my code. The errors are given below:

```
  File "E:\workspace\python\web\Book_Review_App\Book\urls.py", line 13, in <module>
    url(r'^books/', include("Review.urls", namespace='reviews')),
  File "E:\workspace\python\web\Book_Review_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 39, in include
    'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

Please help.

Comment: What version of django are you using

Comment: I am using django 2.0.1

Comment: Can you add the code for Review.urls.py

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The app_name needs to be set in your app's urls.py not the main urls.py.

In review.urls.py add the following,

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url 
from django.contrib import admin 
from .views import ( ReviewUpdate, ReviewDelete, )

app_name = 'Review'

urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^reviews/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', ReviewUpdate.as_view(), name='review_update'),
    url(r'^reviews/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', ReviewDelete.as_view(), name='review_delete'),
]
```

and remove the app_name from the main urls

EDIT: for the admin issue that the op mentioned in the comments,
in the main urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define app_name in urls.py and pass urlconf_module in tuple . Here is example

```
app_name = "example"
from typing import NamedTuple
class NamedURL(NamedTuple):
    urlconf_module: None
    app_name: None

daily_urls = NamedURL(<your custom urls in list>, "example")

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^daily/', include(daily_urls, namespace='daily')),
]
```